# responseString changed after update Alamofire from 5.0 to 5.3

Tags: ios, alamofire

The json I received:

```
{
    "buyer": {
        "tmallMemberLevel": 0
    },
    "consumerProtection": {
        "items": [{
            "desc": "ÕýÆ·±£ÕÏ£¬¼ÙÒ»ÅâËÄ",
            "title": "¼ÙÒ»ÅâËÄ",
            "type": 0
        }, {
            "desc": "³ÏÐÅÓÃ»§ÔÚÍË»õ¼Ä³öºó£¬ÏíÊÜ¼«ËÙÍË¿îµ½ÕË",
            "title": "¼«ËÙÍË¿î",
            "type": 0
        }, {
            "desc": "Âú×ãÏàÓ¦Ìõ¼þÊ±£¬Ïû·ÑÕß¿ÉÉêÇë ¡°ÆßÌìÎÞÀíÓÉÍË»»»õ¡±",
            "title": "ÆßÌìÎÞÀíÓÉÍË»»",
            "type": 0
        }]
    }
}
```

With Alamofire 5.0 responseString is:

```
{"buyer":{"tmallMemberLevel":0},"consumerProtection":{"items":[{"desc":"正品保障，假一赔四","title":"假一赔四","type":0},{"desc":"诚信用户在退货寄出后，享受极速退款到账","title":"极速退款","type":0},{"desc":"满足相应条件时，消费者可申请 “七天无理由退换货”","title":"七天无理由退换"
```

**The Chinese show correctly.**

However, with Alamofire 5.3, the responseString is:

```
{"buyer":{"tmallMemberLevel":0},"consumerProtection":{"items":[{"desc":"ÕýÆ·±£ÕÏ£¬¼ÙÒ»ÅâËÄ","title":"¼ÙÒ»ÅâËÄ","type":0},{"desc":"³ÏÐÅÓÃ»§ÔÚÍË»õ¼Ä³öºó£¬ÏíÊÜ¼«ËÙÍË¿îµ½ÕË","title":"¼«ËÙÍË¿î","type":0},{"desc":"Âú×ãÏàÓ¦Ìõ¼þÊ±£¬Ïû·ÑÕß¿ÉÉêÇë ¡°ÆßÌìÎÞÀíÓÉÍË»»»õ¡±"
```

The Chinese change to messy code.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use GBK encoding to response string:

```
extension String.Encoding {
    
    public static var GB_18030_2000: String.Encoding {
        let cfEncoding = CFStringEncodings.GB_18030_2000
        let resEncoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(cfEncoding.rawValue))
        return String.Encoding(rawValue: resEncoding)
    }
    
}
```